# Add event listener to dynamically created elements only and not on other children

Tags: javascript, jquery, django-templates

I have the following jquery code:

```
function generateTableRow() {
    var emptyColumn = document.createElement('tr');
    emptyColumn.innerHTML = '<td><a class="cut">-</a><span class="itemcode" contenteditable></span></td>' +
        '<td colspan="2"><span contenteditable></span></td>' +
        '<td><span contenteditable>100.00</span></td>' +
        '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>' +
        '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>'+
        '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>' +
        '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>'+
        '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>' +
        '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>' +
        '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>' ;
    itembound();
    return emptyColumn;
}
```

Now, the function itembound() is intended to attach an onfocus and onblur event listener to the new emptycolumn, which is dynamically generated.

However, what this does is it attaches one event listener to all the child elements, every time it is called.

As a result, what I'm having is:
If I'm having five rows (for example), the first row is having 5 handlers, the second row 4, and so on.

My question is how can I add this event handler to only the new child element, ignoring the older ones.

**Edit 1**

Really sorry for the delay. I thank you all for the answer and help.

As requested the itembound() code is as follows:

```
function itembound()
{

$("#inventory_table .itemcode").on("focus", function(){
$(this).data("initialText", $(this).html());
});

$("#inventory_table .itemcode").on("blur", function(){
    if ($(this).data("initialText") !== $(this).html()) {
        alert($(this).html())
    }
});

}
```

I'm just recognizing the change in the text and putting an alert. Once its successfully done, I would use AJAX to communicate the data to the backend.

Thank You

Comment: You can use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Comment: Can you provide `itembound` code

Comment: Are you using javascript addEventListener?or using jQuery bind()/on() methoud? If you can give the code of itemcode(), it would help to give better answer.

Comment: I used event delegation as Rejith said and it seems to work fine!!! I daresay, great! Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change `itembound` function to specify on which element bind the listeners

`itembound(emptyColumn)` will help

```
function generateTableRow() {

    var emptyColumn = document.createElement('tr');
    emptyColumn.innerHTML = '<td><a class="cut">-</a><span class="itemcode" contenteditable></span></td>' +
        '<td colspan="2"><span contenteditable></span></td>' +
        '<td><span contenteditable>100.00</span></td>' +
        '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>' +
        '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>'+
        '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>' +
        '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>'+
        '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>' +
        '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>' +
        '<td><span contenteditable></span></td>' ;
    itembound(emptyColumn); // bound listeners to emptyColumn only
    return emptyColumn;
}
function itembound(elm)
{
 $(".itemcode",elm).on("focus", function(){
    $(this).data("initialText", $(this).html());
    });

    $(".itemcode",elm).on("blur", function(){
        if ($(this).data("initialText") !== $(this).html()) {
            alert($(this).html())
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Thanks Jags for your answer!!